# SQL Server Transaction Replication - Chave Primaria

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, replicação

Eu tenho um ambiente com 2 filiais, cada filial tem que ter um servidor de aplicação com um SQL SERVER instalado, eu configurei o [transaction replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) que está funcionando perfeitamente, porém se 2 pessoas em filiais diferentes estiverem inserindo dados na mesma tabela ao mesmo tempo eu recebo o erro de chave primaria violada.

Eu gostaria de uma sugestão de configuração para esse ambiente, eu preciso realmente manter um servidor em cada filial para que a aplicação fique rápida.

Obrigado!

Comment: acho que fazendo lock table isso se resolve http://stackoverflow.com/a/23759307/3130590

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que você esta utilizando um identity como chave.

Minha solução para você é criar uma coluna (caso não exista) que indique qual filial esta salvando dados e altere sua tabela para que essa coluna também faça parte da sua chave.

Outra solução, mas que só serve se aplica ao seu ambiente atual com 2 filiais seria de recriar os identity's nas tabelas para que uma filial so tivesse id's pares e na outra somente id's impares.

Mas não indico essa segunda opção, por N motivos.